# Windows Explorer like Mouse effects on Button

Tags: c#, winforms, frames, effect

Does anybody know how to do Windows Explorer Frame Effect in C# WinForms? I mean, when the mouse is over the button the image changes and also when you click on the button it changes again (See image below). I want to do this with a single PNG Image.

This is what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- You can do that very easily **if your image is semi-transparent and rectangular**, as  `PNG` files can be.

You need to set the `Button.FlatStyle = Flat` and pick two colors for the `FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor` and the `FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor`.

You also should set the  `FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0`.

Now the colors will shine thought the image to indicate the current state.

- **If your Image is not rectangular**, as the one you have shown, this solution will not work well: The areas outside of the image will also be colored; this is also true if you try to restrict the display `Region` of the `Button`. (Which feels like a bug..)

Instead you may need to manipulate the `Image` itself.

Here is an example using orange and green:

[image]

I store the original in the `Tag` of the `Button`:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    button1.Tag = button1.BackgroundImage;
}
```

The four mouse events take care of both `Disposing` of the old `Bitmaps` and setting new, shaded ones:

```
private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (button1.BackgroundImage != button1.Tag) button1.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
    button1.BackgroundImage = shade((Bitmap)(button1.Tag), Color.Orange, 3);
}

private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (button1.BackgroundImage != button1.Tag) button1.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
    button1.BackgroundImage = (Bitmap)button1.Tag;
}

private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (button1.BackgroundImage != button1.Tag) button1.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
    button1.BackgroundImage = shade((Bitmap)(button1.Tag), Color.Green, 3);
}

private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (button1.BackgroundImage != button1.Tag) button1.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
    button1.BackgroundImage = shade((Bitmap)(button1.Tag), Color.Orange, 3);
}
```

They make use of a fast image shading routine, that takes the `Image`, a `Color` and a strength (1-10), all checks are omitted and a `PixelFormat` of `32bpp` is expected..:

```
Bitmap shade(Bitmap bmp0, Color hue, int strength)
{
    int Bpp = 4;
    Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(bmp0.Width, bmp0.Height, bmp0.PixelFormat);

    var bmpData0 = bmp0.LockBits(
                    new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp0.Width, bmp0.Height),
                    ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp0.PixelFormat);
    var bmpData1 = bmp1.LockBits(
                    new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp1.Width, bmp1.Height),
                    ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp1.PixelFormat);

    int len = bmpData0.Height * bmpData0.Stride;
    byte[] data0 = new byte[len];
    byte[] data1 = new byte[len];
    Marshal.Copy(bmpData0.Scan0, data0, 0, len);
    Marshal.Copy(bmpData1.Scan0, data1, 0, len);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += Bpp)
    {
      data1[i + 0] = (byte)((data0[i + 0] + hue.B / 10f * strength) / (strength / 10f + 1));
      data1[i + 1] = (byte)((data0[i + 1] + hue.G / 10f * strength) / (strength / 10f + 1));
      data1[i + 2] = (byte)((data0[i + 2] + hue.R / 10f * strength) / (strength / 10f + 1));
      data1[i + 3] = data0[i + 3];
    }

    Marshal.Copy(data1, 0, bmpData1.Scan0, len);
    bmp0.UnlockBits(bmpData0);
    bmp1.UnlockBits(bmpData1);
    return bmp1;
}
```

You may want to wrap it all in a `Button` subclass and od course play with the `Colors` and strengths..

Comment: I've tried this code, but this is not exactly what I want. Do you know about Rainmeter? Well, there's a meter called "BUTTON". I want to do exactly that effect. I'm using PerPixelAlphaBlended Forms, by the way.

Comment: No, I don't know this. What is the difference?

Comment: The Button meter is a single rectangular PNG image with normal State, MouseOver State and MouseDown state. As I shown in the question. Its just a image with frames.